# Comparison of ZeroMQ's latency / metrics with that of its competitors

Tags: zeromq, low-latency

Does anyone know where you can find performance details on ZeroMQ latency vs. competitors like 29 West LBM?

Looks considerably cheaper, but I cannot find any metrics to decide which is more suitable.

Comment: I'm using the java binding as well.

Answer (score 3):

Both ZeroMQ and 29West LBM use a brokerless approach to messaging and support the same transports (TCP, UDP, IB) so latency should be broadly similar.

ZeroMQ has more of a toolkit based approach so you can assemble what you need where as 29 West offers a number of 'add ons' (persistence, cacheing, etc.) which may get you started faster or in an Enterprise environment, be accepted more easily.